# Get a list of dates responding to rules

Tags: c#, linq, datetime, collections

I have a list of dates like:

> - 21/12/2019
> - 22/12/2019
> - 22/12/2019
> - 24/12/2019
> - 26/12/2019
> - 26/12/2019
> - 27/12/2019

I have the rule model defined as:

```
public class Timing
{
    public int PeriodNbMinutes { get; set; }
    public int NbTimes { get; set; }
    public bool IsConsecutive { get; set; }
    public int Multiplicity { get; set; }
}
```

Now I have the rule like: I want to find all dates where:

Dates which appears 3 times in 2 days and for twice times

So I should get two groups (I don't want to reuse dates already in a group):

First

> 1st: 21/12/2019 - 22/12/2019 - 22/12/2019

Second

> 2nd: 26/12/2019 - 26/12/2019 - 27/12/2019

I then have my rule like this:

```
this.PeriodMinutes = 2680;
this.NbTimes = 2;
this.Multiplicity = 2;
this.IsConsecutive=true;
```

> Edited

```
    public int PeriodNbMinutes { get; set; }
    public int NbTimes { get; set; }
    public bool IsConsecutive { get; set; }
    public int Multiplicity { get; set; }

    internal bool Test(List<DateTime> metrics)
    {
        bool res = false;
        int times = 0;
        int multiple=0;
        TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(0, PeriodNbMinutes, 0);

        for (int i = 0; i < metrics.Count; i++)
        {
            var dates = metrics.Skip(i);

            var selectedDts = metrics.Zip(dates, (dtFirst, dtNext) => (dtNext - dtFirst).Ticks < ts.Ticks);

            if (selectedDts.Count() > 0)
            {
                res = true;
                times++;

                if (times == Multiplicity)
                {
                    multiple++;
                    if (multiple == Multiplicity)
                        return true;

                    // Consecutive???
                }
                else res = false;
            }
            else
            {
                res = false;
                times = 0;
            }
        }
        return res;

    }
```

---

How can I find these groups with Linq? I tried with TimeSpan but can't get it to work.

Additionally, In the two groups selected I need to know if they are consecutive or not.

I tried a lot of different solutions but nothing good. How can I do it simply?

Thanks,

Comment: What have you tried _exactly_? Can you show your [MCVE] ? What is _not_ working exactly?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your message. I added my code.

Comment: By Lync do you mean Linq? Lync is a chat program, a bit like Skype

Comment: What is a consecutive date? You list looks sorted; does this mean that all the dates are consecutive?

Comment: Yes Linq. Consecutive it must be: 25-26 and 27. Not 25-26-26. I corrected. Thanks @CaiusJard

Comment: So 24th is rejected because it's on its own with no date either side. What if there were dates of 20, 21, 21, 22, 23, 24, 26? Is 20 to 22 (4 dates) one group and then 23,24 is no group (doesn't occur 3 times date that is between 22 to 24)? Or does it that three dates of 20,21,21 is a group of 20-21 and then 22,23,24 is another triple that makes group 22-24?

Comment: I'm trying to work out if logic is like "3 dates in a row" or "any number of dates so long as they are within 2 days of the first date"

Comment: They must be consecutively and independently in the period.